# Why do I get an error when I put a call for the output of a function (defined within a function) *after* the function definition, and not before?

Tags: matlab, function, nested

My code does what I want it to do, but I want to understand why it does what it does. I find that in MATLAB if I call for the output of a function after the definition of the function, I get an error, but not if I call it before the function's definition. My impression is that MATLAB is putting the cart before the horse, and I'd like to know why I am mistaken in that impression.

```
function [out,outt]=f_testFunctionWithinFunction(arg_in)
    % function has to be invoked BEFORE its definition.
    out=f_inside(arg_in); 

    function use=f_inside(argg_in),
        use=sin(argg_in);
    return

    outt=f_inside(arg_in); 

return
```

The expression `out=f_testFunctionWithinFunction(5)` yields `-0.9589=sin(5)`. However, `[out,outt]=f_testFunctionWithinFunction(5)` yields an error message, due to asking for `"outt"`. Why?

Comment: If you want to know how to define functions you can read about [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html). Also [`local functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) should be distinguished from [`nested functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should end functions with `end`, instead of `return`. try:

```
function [out,outt]=f_testFunctionWithinFunction(arg_in)
% function has to be invoked BEFORE its definition.
disp('test')
out=f_inside(arg_in);

function use=f_inside(argg_in),
use=sin(argg_in);
end

outt=f_inside(arg_in);

end
```